# Can I create a custom attribute that runs a codebehind method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I added an `onkeyup` attribute on `Page_Load` for a `TextBox`. I have it so that it is able to run a JavaScript function fine. I was wondering if I can change it to run a method in the code-behind file. I tried `this.methodname`, but it asks for a string as a parameter.

The `TextBox` in question:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCurrBlk" runat="server" onkeyup="txtUpdate()"
     style="width:80px" Text='<%#Eval("currentBlack") %>'
     AutoPostBack="true" />
```

Under `page_load` in this C# file:

```
txtCurrBlkTotal.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "CallScript(this)");
```

The function I want to run in the same code behind file:

```
protected void keypressUpdateTotals()
{
    readingTextChanged();
    updateTotals();
}
```

So the `onkeyup` will currently run whatever JavaScript function I set it to, but I need it to run a method inside the code-behind instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `TextBox` control only has the server-side `TextChanged` event, and you cannot easily make a "custom" server-side event. However, you can let your JavaScript `CallScript()` function make a post-back to the server by calling the `_postback()` function.

Add the `OnTextChanged` attribute to your `TextBox` control (I recommend removing the `AutoPostBack` attribute too, but that's up to you):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCurrBlkTotal" runat="server"
             onkeyup="CallScript(this)"
             OnTextChanged="txtCurrBlk_TextChanged" />
```

I've added the `onkeyup` directly here, but you can use `txtCurrBlkTotal.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "CallScript(this)");`, if you want.

Now, at the end of the `CallScript()` function, call the `_postback()` function for your `TextBox` control:

```
function CallScript(sender) {
    //...
    __doPostBack("<%= txtCurrBlkTotal.ClientID %>", "");
}
```

This will post-back to the server every time the `onKeyUp` event is fired. You can capture and process that in the `TextChanged` event:

```
protected void txtCurrBlkTotal_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    keypressUpdateTotals();
}
```

Alternatively, you can make your JavaScript `CallScript()` function make an Ajax call to your code-behind `keypressUpdateTotals()` function. I think that's a better solution, but you can decide for yourself.